# Disable menu items when table removed from editor

Tags: c#

I have a small text editor which allows a table to be inserted through a menu bar.

When my form loads the only thing enabled in my menu drop down is "insert table". Once I click on insert table all other menu items are now enabled.

What I am trying to do and can't is when I remove the table from the editor I would like to re-disable the items that were enabled when the table was placed in the editor.

Code I have so far is:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RMIInsertRow.Enabled = false;
        RMIInsertCol.Enabled = false;
        RMIMergeCells.Enabled = false;
        RMISplitCellHoriz.Enabled = false;
        RMIDeleteCells.Enabled = false;
        RMIRowPos.Enabled = false;
        RMIRowHeight.Enabled = false;
        RMIHeaderRow.Enabled = false;
        RMIKeepRowTogether.Enabled = false;
        RMIRowTextFlow.Enabled = false;
        RMICellWidth.Enabled = false;
        RMICellBorderWidth.Enabled = false;
        RMICellBorderColor.Enabled = false;
        RMICellShading.Enabled = false;
        RMICellColor.Enabled = false;
        RMICellVertAlign.Enabled = false;
        RMICellRotateText.Enabled = false;
        RMISelectCurCol.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void RMIInsertTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.TestCommand(test.TABLE_INSERT);

        if (sender == RMIInsertTable)
        {
            RMIInsertRow.Enabled = true;
            RMIInsertCol.Enabled = true;
            RMIMergeCells.Enabled = true;
            RMISplitCellHoriz.Enabled = true;
            RMIDeleteCells.Enabled = true;
            RMIRowPos.Enabled = true;
            RMIRowHeight.Enabled = true;
            RMIHeaderRow.Enabled = true;
            RMIKeepRowTogether.Enabled = true;
            RMIRowTextFlow.Enabled = true;
            RMICellWidth.Enabled = true;
            RMICellBorderWidth.Enabled = true;
            RMICellBorderColor.Enabled = true;
            RMICellShading.Enabled = true;
            RMICellColor.Enabled = true;
            RMICellVertAlign.Enabled = true;
            RMICellRotateText.Enabled = true;
            RMISelectCurCol.Enabled = true;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: How are the tables removed? Is there a RMIRemoveTable_Click event?

Comment: Nope...just removing them by selecting them and delete or backspace.

Comment: Hmmm...Are you able to easily/quickly identify if the text editor contains a table or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I can insert the table and the code will enable all the menu items and I can use the items to manipulate the table but when I delete the table the items are all still enabled. I hope that answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you need to be able to accurately identify when the table has been deleted so that you can disable the table controls. But this becomes more complicated if they can add more than one table. If that is the case, then you need to be able to identify if a table has 'focus' or not, so that you can enable/disable the table controls appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Ulric...I will look into that. The user can add more than one table but the controls should stay enabled until there are no more tables left on the document. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good luck - it sounds like a tricky thing to get right.